# Why is $PAP^{-1}$ not always equal to $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

A true/false question on my Introduction to Linear Algebra exam review asks

"The matrix $PAP^{-1}$ may not equal $A$." We've been taught that $PP^{-1}$ is equal to the identity matrix. Multiplying any matrix by the identity matrix yields itself, so why wouldn't the answer to this be false?

Any information or explanations would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There is no commutative law in matrices multiplication.

Comment: I.e., $PA$ is not always equal to $AP$ when $A$ and $P$ are matrices

Comment: Take two 2x2 matrices A and P and experiment.

Comment: Reinforcing the previous comment: the best way to prove the statement true is to find $A$ and $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}\neq A.$ If your first attempt with $2\times2$ matrices ends up with two equal matrices, try again. You need to find a pair of matrices $A$ and $P$ that don't commute with each other, that is, you get different results from $AP$ than from $PA.$

Comment: Consider $P=P^{-1}=\pmatrix{0& 1\\1& 0}$ and $A=\pmatrix{3& 0\\0& 1}$.  Can you picture how these transform $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple version:

The matrix space does not commute; that is to say, we **don't have** $AB = BA$, so we **don't have**
$$PAP^{-1} = PP^{-1}A = IA = A,$$ where the first equation does not hold.

For example, let
$$ P = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right), A = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right),
$$
thus $$P^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right), PAP^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{matrix}\right).$$

Complex version:

The left multiplication of the matrix is changed it by rows; the right multiplication corresponds to column transformation. As the example above,
$$PA = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right),$$
which is just adding the second row of $A$ to the first one. If then $PA$ is multiplied by $P^{-1}$ at the left, everything will turn back since
$$P^{-1}PA=IA=A.$$
However, it is multiplied from the right, which no longer means row transformation. $P^{-1}$ will be "subtract the second column by the first one". Then $$(PA)P^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1\end{matrix}\right) \neq A$$

Answer (score 4):

It is true that, for matrices $A$ and $P$, $PAP^{-1}$ may not equal $A$.

If matrix multiplication were commutative, then we would have $PAP^{-1}=APP^{-1}=AI=A$,

but it is not generally true that $PA=AP$

(though it is true when $A=P^{-1}, I, P, $ or $P^2$, et al.).

For example, try $P=P^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$, which switches $x$ and $y$,

and $A=\pmatrix{3&0\\0&1}$, which stretches $x$ threefold.